# Wordpress Menu Display Subs From Parent

Tags: wordpress

I have a menu that i've created in Wordpress from Appearance->Menus called Main.

It outputs

- Parent One

  - Sub One
  - Sub Two
  - Sub Three
- Parent Two

  - Sub One
  - Sub Two
  - Sub Three

etc

if I'm on Parent One->Sub Two how can I display all the links associated with Parent One in the sidebar and highlight Sub Two because thats the page im on from my menu?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a menu widget in the sidebar, when you inspect the elements of the menu, do your li tags (top-level and sub-menus) have classes like "current_page_item" and "current_page_ancestor"? If so, you can target those classes in your css to hide/show the sub-menus that you want and change the color of the link of the current page.

For example:

```
    .sidebar .menu .sub-menu {
        display: none;
        margin-left: 35px;
    }
    .sidebar .menu .current_page_item .sub-menu, 
    .sidebar .menu .current_page_ancestor .sub-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .sidebar .menu li a:hover, 
    .sidebar .menu li.current-menu-item > a {
        color: #0284e8;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```